# Fortran ouput particle data to .vtu file for paraview

Tags: fortran, vtk, paraview, particles, post-processing

I am trying to write a Fortran subroutine to output (randomly positioned) particle data to a .vtu file for post-processing in Paraview. The program produces a file which is formatted as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<VTKFile type= "UnstructuredGrid"  version= "0.1"  byte_order= "BigEndian">                         
 <UnstructuredGrid>                                                                                 
  <Piece NumberOfPoints="6664" NumberOfCells="0">                                                   
   <PointData Scalars="Pressure" Vectors="Velocity">                                                
    <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Pressures" format="ascii">                                      
    ...    
    </DataArray>                                                                                    
    <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Density" format="ascii">                                        
    ...    
    </DataArray>                                                                                    
    <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Mass" format="ascii">                                           
    ...
    </DataArray>                                                                                    
    <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Scalarplot" format="ascii">                                     
    ...
    </DataArray>                                                                                    
    <DataArray type="Float32" Name="Velocity" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii">                
    ... ... ...
    </DataArray>                                                                                    
   </PointData>                                                                                     
   <Points> 
    <DataArray type="Float32" NumberOfComponents="3" format="ascii"> 
    ... ... ...
    </DataArray>                                                                                    
   </Points>                                                                                        
   <Cells>                                                                                          
    <DataArray type="Int32" Name="connectivity" format="ascii">                                     
    ...
    </DataArray>                                                                                    
    <DataArray type="Int32" Name="offsets" format="ascii">                                          
    ...  
    </DataArray>                                                                                    
    <DataArray type="Int32" Name="types" format="ascii">                                            
    ...       
    </DataArray>
   </Cells>
  </Piece>
 </UnstructuredGrid>
</VTKFile>
```

The code is based on the subroutine in the [SPHYSICS](https://wiki.manchester.ac.uk/sphysics/index.php/SPHYSICS_Home_Page) program and the file format [documentation](http://www.vtk.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/file-formats.pdf).

Paraview loads the file but I cannot visualise the particles using their coordinates or any of the field variables. Could this be due to a problem with the .vtu file?

The scalarplot value is set to 1 for each particle and is probably unnecessary. I just included it in case I wanted the particles to be coloured differently at some point (probably should be a Float).

Does this have to contain Cell data? The connectivity and offesets have just been set to the particle/point number and the types have just been set to "1" for each particle/point. Could this be leading to the problem?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question: you're quite sure aren't you that the size of the points to be plotted has been set to be large enough to see ?

Comment: By no means a stupid question - I did check that. I _might_ have just figured it out. My original format specifier for the particle position was "*". I changed this to "("//TRIM(no_dim)//"(4X, E15.8))" and now Paraview is displaying the points. Should I delete this post or leave it as a reference? My questions above still stand but might not be relevant to this community.

Comment: Don't leave the question unanswered -- lots of SO users trawl for unanswered questions.  So either delete it or answer it yourself, this is entirely acceptable behaviour.  You can even, later, accept your own answer.  Personally I think that with a clear explanation of the fix that you adopted the Q&A are at least as useful as more than 50% of other Qs and As here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there is nothing wrong with the format of the output above. The problem was with the format specifiers used on the "..." components. Some of these were specified using "*" which must have produced an inconsistent / incompatible output file. By specifying these specifically (e.g. "//TRIM(no_dim)//"(4X, E15.8))" for the coordinates), the file worked with Paraview. For those who are interested a .pvd file should also be written (which is file which points to the .pvu files) in order to produce an animation in Paraview.